# How should I write a matrix onto a text in Hex format?

Tags: matlab, file-handling, printf

I have a matrix, say:

```
M = [1000 1350;2000 2040;3000 1400];
```

I wish to write this matrix onto a text file in the hex format, like this:

```
0x000003e8 0x00000bb8  
0x000007d0 0x000007f8   
0x00000bb8 0x00000578
```

I considered using the function `dec2hex` but it's very slow and inefficient. It also gives me the output as a string, which I don't know how to restructure for my above required format.

MATlab directly converts hex numbers to decimal when reading from a text file, ex. when using the function `fscanf(fid,'%x')`.

Can we do the exact same thing while writing a matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `%x` format string. For the sake of demonstration, see an example with `sprintf` below. If you want to write to a file, you will have to use `fprintf`.

```
M = [1000 1350;2000 2040;3000 1400];
str = sprintf('0x%08x\t0x%08x\n', M')
```

this results in

```
str =

0x000003e8  0x00000546
0x000007d0  0x000007f8
0x00000bb8  0x00000578
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `num2str` with a format string:

```
str = num2str(M, '0x%08x ');
```

which returns

```
str =

0x000003e8 0x00000546
0x000007d0 0x000007f8
0x00000bb8 0x00000578
```

Using this instead of `sprintf` you do not need to repeat the format string for each column.